# Doing an equation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have this code and it always outputs 9 no mater what number i put in the textbbox. The equation is 0.25x^(2)+9, the ^(2) means squared.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function calc() {
        var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
        var one = parseInt(0.25*number);
        var two = parseInt(one*one);
        var three = parseInt(two+9) ;
        var sum = parseInt(three);
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = sum;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>$10 fee and 2 Commands are free!</p>
<input id="input" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="1000"></input><div id="num"></div>
<button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
</body>
```

help?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3uzztnq/)

Comment: You don't need to keep calling `parseInt()` like that.

Comment: And maybe you should use `parseFloat`. Here more [information](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp)

Comment: [Here it is (without the excess `parseInt` calls)](https://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/4yrLjwz8/) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: you also have a mathematical mistake if you do: `one = 0.25*x`  ,  `two = one^2` it WILL NOT BE LIKE `0.25*x^2` , it will actually be `0.25^2 * x^2`

Comment: Also, you can just use `+` before `document.getElementById('input').value` instead of parseInt i think to convert it to a number.

Comment: Also your code is evaluating `(0.25x)^2 + 9` since you're squaring *after* multiplying by 0.25. In traditional algebraic notation, `0.25x^2` would square `x` *before* the multiplication.

Comment: @Arg0n: Converting to a number is what `parseInt` does.

Comment: @squint `parseInt()` converts to an **integer** - fractional part is lost. Whether that's what the OP wants for the initial treatment of the input value, we can't say :)

Comment: @squint Yeah, but you can shorten it to: `+document.getElementById('input').value;`

Comment: @Arg0n: Yes you're right, I misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: Always leave rounding to the end of your operations. Drop all those parseInt calls.

Comment: @Arg0n Actually do not need to use `parseInt()` or `+` operator. `<input type="number">` has `.valueAsNumber` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you are casting it to an int everytime you are rounding everything down to 0 and then when you add +9 you alwasy get 9 as the answer so do:

```
    function calc() {
        var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
        var one = 0.25*number;
        var two = one*one;
        var three = two+9;
        var sum = three;
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = sum;
    }
```

**In addtion you have a methmetical mistake**

```
var one = 0.25*number;
var two = one*one;
```

two will be like saying `two = o.25^2 * x^2` and not `two = 0.25 * x^2` like you want so change it to:

```
function calc() {
        var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
        var one = number*number;
        var two = 0.25*one;
        var three = two+9;
        var sum = three;
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = sum;
    }
```

And there is an even easyer way:

```
        function calc() {
            var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
            var sum = 0.25*(number*number) + 9;
            document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = sum;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

> I have this code and it always outputs 9 no mater what number i put in
>   the textbbox

That is because when you do `(0.25 * 0.25)`, it becomes `0.625`. and `parseInt` on it makes it `0`.

Which means unless your number is less than 4, it will always print 9 since `(0+9)` -> `9` (0 after parseInt)

Also, your code is outputting `10` if number is `4` and `13` if number is `8`.

Right formula would be

```
sum = Math.pow( number * 0.25, 2 ) + 9
```

Comment: `sum = Math.pow( number * 0.25, 2 ) + 9` that is not correct because (0.25*x)^2 =/= 0.25*x^2 , it should be `0.25 * Math.pow( number,  2 )  + 9`

Comment: Ok, so when i run it and enter 2 then output should be 10 not 9.25.

Comment: @DonatPants Fair enough! I went with what OP has attempted rather what he described in problem statement